# CUDA array addition and block size

Tags: cuda

```
__global__ void add(int *a, int *b, int *c, int n) 
{
    size_t index = threadIdx. + blockId.x * blockDim.x;
    if(index < n)
    c[index] = a[index] + b[index] ;

}
```

Hello, I am trying to remember the reason why the if test is necessary. I remember it is something about block size in this kernel. Is it just about array bounds ?

What will happen for threads whose index are above n ?

Comment: Imagine you are launching blocks of 1024 threads. Your array size is 4000, so that the number of blocks launched is 4(4096 threads). In the last block, the last 96 threads will try to write to an illegal memory location if you don't check the bounds.

Answer (score 1):

> I remember it is something about block size in this kernel. Is it just about array bounds ?

Yes. Unless the number of elements in the input and output arrays exactly match the number of threads launched, then out of bounds memory access would occur. In practice that is rarely the case, and it would be normal to round up the grid size to ensure there are more threads than required for the array sizes. The alternative would be to run less threads than inputs, which would leave part of the inputs and outputs unprocessed, and that doesn't make a lot of sense.

> What will happen for threads whose index are above n ?

Nothing. They will branch around the memory access portion of the code and exit without touching memory that would otherwise result in a runtime error for out-of-bounds memory access.